# Cannot edit project properties in Rider ide

Tags: c#, ide, rider, project-properties

The project properties just don't open, and the Rider says "editing properties is not supported for this item" [error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/chZ1x.png). It happens for every project, but in Visual Studio I can edit project properties normally. How to fix it?

Thanks for any help

Comment: You have to create a new issue in JetBrains public issue tracker: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/newIssue?project=RIDER and attach IDE logs (Help -> Show Log In)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved by switching the used MSBuild version from 17 to 16 in (Settings -> Build, Execution, Deployment -> Toolset and Build)